# How to run mySQL script to cloud build

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have created database on GCP and want to create tables by cloud build.
cloudbuild.yaml:

```
 -  name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args: ['./dbFile/dev_sh.sh', './dbFile/dev.sql']
```

dev_sh.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "No arguments supplied"
fi
mysql -h "mob-dev:us-central1:pk" -u "root" -p "root" "pk" < "./dbFile/dev.sql"
```

Getting Issue:
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
./dbFile/dev_sh.sh: line 5: mysql: command not found

Comment: You shouldn't put private information publicly, such as the instance connection name, the user or the password. I suggest you edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the `mysql` client first, as the builder doesn't contain it by default:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
  - '-c'
  - |
    apt update
    apt install -y mysql-client
    ./dbFile/dev_sh.sh ./dbFile/dev.sql
```

About the syntax, check [this document](https://medium.com/@davidstanke/mastering-google-cloud-build-config-syntax-8c3024607daf).